# Tika Bridge is deprecated in Hibernate Search 6. Alternatives?

Tags: migration, hibernate-search, apache-tika

In Hibernate Search 6 the Apache Tika bridge has disappeared:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/#tikabridge

What is the best way to index the contents of a PDF or a Word document file now? Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you trust the documents, a few lines of code will let you call Apache Tika and get the contents. If you don't trust the documents, you'll want to use the Apache Tika server so all the work runs in a different JVM, that's a bit more devops-type work to setup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own bridge, as [documented here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-valuebridge).

Something like this:

```java
public class TikaBridge implements ValueBridge<String, String> {
    private final Parser parser;

    public TikaBridge() {
        parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    }

    @Override
    public String toIndexedValue(String documentPath, ValueBridgeToIndexedValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try (InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(documentPath)) {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            WriteOutContentHandler contentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler(writer);
            Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
            ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
            parser.parse(input, contentHandler, metadata, parseContext);
            return writer.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then implement an annotation and its processor:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD }) 
@PropertyMapping(processor = @PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessorRef( 
        type = TikaField.Processor.class
))
@Documented 
@Repeatable(TikaField.List.class) 
public @interface TikaField {

    String name() default ""; 

    ContainerExtraction extraction() default @ContainerExtraction(); 

    @Documented
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface List {
        TikaField[] value();
    }

    class Processor implements PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessor<TikaField> { 
        @Override
        public void process(PropertyMappingStep mapping, TikaField annotation,
                PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessorContext context) {
            TikaBridge bridge = new TikaBridge();
            mapping.genericField(annotation.name().isEmpty() ? null : annotation.name()) 
                    .valueBridge(bridge) 
                    .extractors(context.toContainerExtractorPath(annotation.extraction())); 
        }
    }
}
```

Then just use it on your model:

```java
public class MyEntity {

    // ...

    @TikaField
    String myDocument;

}
```

Should you need any parameters, you can add them to your annotation and pass them along to your bridge's constructor.

If you need to populate multiple fields from a single PDF/Word document, for example to index metadata as well as the document content, then you will have to implement a [PropertyBridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-field-bridge) instead: it allows populating multiple fields instead of just one. That's a bit more complicated, but similar.